# What is size of last row in array based heap

Tags: math, heap, binary-tree

In an array based heap, assuming items are inserted in breadth first order size of each row at depth D can be easily evaluated. As Heap is balanced tree.

```
RowSize = pow(2, D);
```

Maximum depth can be also easily calculated.

```
MaxD = log2(Count);
```

But what is the size of last row. How to know number of deepest leafs?

Theorical maximum is MaxD to power of 2. But it can have less than that. I want to know that number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last row size is

```
Count - (int)pow(2, maxD) + 1;
```

Thanks to wolframAlpba for revealing formula.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+2%5Ex+x%3D0+to+n

Comment: You need to truncate `maxD` and `pow(2, maxD)`. Otherwise, you'll incorrect results. I think you want `Count - (int)pow(2, (int)maxD) + 1`

Comment: Indeed. I fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: This is a geometric sum, no need for Wolfram|Alpha for that! :)

Comment: I just realized `2^maxD` is `2^log2(Count)` so mathematically `Count - (2^maxD) + 1` equals to 1. so truncation plays important rule here!